# No mapping file found named 'MyBundle.Entity.Review.php' for class 'MyyBundle\Entity\Review'

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, orm, doctrine

Im new in symfony2 and I have a big problem here, when I tried to save some data for a entity I got this error

> No mapping file found named 'MyBundle.Entity.Review.php' for class 'MyBundle\Entity\Review'

I have read all the answers related to this issue and I can not find the solution. Please, can you help me?

here is my entity code.

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Review
 */
class Review
{
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $score;

/**
 * @var int
 */
private $total;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return Review
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set score
 *
 * @param string $score
 * @return Review
 */
public function setScore($score)
{
    $this->score = $score;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get score
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getScore()
{
    return $this->score;
}

/**
 * Set total
 *
 * @param integer $total
 * @return Review
 */
public function setTotal($total)
{
    $this->total = $total;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get total
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getTotal()
{
    return $this->total;
}
```

}

This is my controller

```
public function saveReviewAction() { 
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->getPathInfo();
$method = $request->getMethod();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$review = new Review();
$review->setContent('CONTENT');

// tells Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Review (no queries yet)
$em->persist($review);

// actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
$em->flush();

  return new JsonResponse(array('msg' => 'Json','method' => $review->getContent()));
```

}

If I tried php app/console doctrine:mapping:info i got:

> [Exception]
>     You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have enti
>     ties or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No mapping file found named 'MyBundle.Entity.Review.php' for class 'MyyBundle\Entity\Review'

According to this error. Sure there should be an importing related issue. because, Your class is inside MyBundle. App is searching for MyyBundle(there are two 'y's in your My). Check the bundle name and importing lines again.